# Navigate to a specific item inside ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listcollectionview

I'm trying to navigate to a specific item inside a ListCollectionView based on the value of the Date property of SelectedDay.

VM

```
private Day _selectedDay;
public Day SelectedDay    // the Name property
{
     get { return _selectedDay; }
     set { _selectedDay = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}

public ObservableCollection<ShootingDay> AllShootingDayInfo {get; set;}

private ListCollectionView _shootingDayInfoList;
public ListCollectionView ShootingDayInfoList
{
    get
    {
        if (_shootingDayInfoList == null)
        {
            _shootingDayInfoList = new ListCollectionView(AllShootingDayInfo);}
            return _shootingDayInfoList;
    }
    set
    {
        _shootingDayInfoList = value; RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

The `<Day>` object has a property of `Date` and I want that to match with the `Date` Property in the `<ShootingDay>` Object so I can navigate to the item in the `ShootingDayInfoList` where `SelectedDay.Date` matches `Date` of Item inside `ShootingDayInfoList`.

I've tried this but this isn't working since Selected Item is not part of the same object.

```
ShootingDayInfoList.MoveCurrentTo(SelectedDay.Date);
```

How can I make this work? I'm very new to all this.

Comment: have you tried finding the ShootingDay object in the ShootingDayInfoList first? and then use the found object to replace that 'SelectedDay.Date' parameter. You can try finding it using manual loop or Linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Filter` predicate to get the needed item, then remove that `Filter` to bring back all the items back.

Code

```
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vm.ShootingDayInfoList.Count.ToString());
vm.SelectedDay.Date = DateTime.Parse("12/25/2015");

vm.ShootingDayInfoList.Filter = (o) =>
{
    if (((ShootingDay)o).Date.Equals(vm.SelectedDay.Date))
        return true;

    return false;
};

ShootingDay foundItem = (ShootingDay)vm.ShootingDayInfoList.GetItemAt(0);
vm.ShootingDayInfoList.Filter = (o) => { return true; };

vm.ShootingDayInfoList.MoveCurrentTo(foundItem);
```

I have checked the code by using `MoveCurrentToNext() method`, it is working properly.
This approach won't affect your existing code.

2nd approach, use `AllShootingDayInfo` directly or use `SourceCollection` property to get underlying `Collection` :

```
    ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vm.ShootingDayInfoList.Count.ToString());
    vm.SelectedDay.Date = DateTime.Parse("12/23/2015");

    IEnumerable<ShootingDay> underlyingCollection = ((IEnumerable<ShootingDay>)vm.ShootingDayInfoList.SourceCollection);

    ShootingDay d1 = underlyingCollection.FirstOrDefault(dt => dt.Date.Equals(vm.SelectedDay.Date)); 

    vm.ShootingDayInfoList.MoveCurrentTo(d1);
```